# Java Stream why does reduce requires two parameters of the functional Interface?

Tags: java, android, java-stream

In other words, why does reduce require BinaryOperator, or BiFunction interface? Why doesn't it use UnaryOperator, or Function interface instead?

What is the point of having two parameters as the input for the functional interface? (I know it's for accumulation, but why doesn't one parameter suffice?)

Comment: Binary operator is a function which performs reducing operation. It takes two elements as an input and gives back only one. Basically it’s the root part of the reduce operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you compute a single value that depends on all the `Stream` elements with a `UnaryOperator`?

You can apply the `UnaryOperator` on the first element of the `Stream`.

Then you can apply the `UnaryOperator` on the second element of the `Stream`.

But you can't combine the two results.

A `BinaryOperator` can be applied on the first and second elements of the `Stream`.

Then you can apply it on the intermediate result (of the first two elements) and the 3rd element of the `Stream`, to get an intermediate result that depends on the first 3 elements, and so on... until you get a result that depends on all the elements.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. It just appears to me as an instinct that one input is enough and there would be a temporary variable to hold the intermediate result, instead of two parameters :)